# How to reset the film to 1 (it is now on 26) even though I’m on my first few films

Tags: film, 35mm, fujifilm

I’m new to film camera, and currently using a Fujifilm clearshot point & shoot 35mm. When the moment I got my camera, the reading on number of film used is on 20, how can I adjust it to 1?

Comment: Has that number increased with each frame shot and advanced, or with each roll loaded, used, and rewound?

Comment: The film counter will reset to 0 when you open the camera and remove the film. If your camera is not doing that, it may be broken.

Comment: What happens when you take a photo and advance the film? Does the counter go up? Go down? Or stay the same?